# Use index of summation as the order of derivation

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

Given some function `f`, I want to compute the following sum using sympy:

[image: $\sum\limits _{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{d^{i}}{dx^{i}}f$]

In general I want to use the index of summation as the order of differentiation of the function but I could not find out how to do it with `sympy`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: Thanks for editing

Comment: `f` is already a `sympy` function?

Comment: too bad there is no LaTeX rendering on SO (it has been asked multiple times).

Comment: yes it is a sympy function

Comment: and `n` is a fixed integer known in advance?

Comment: yes, sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Given `n` is an `int` you know in advance, you can construct a function:

```
from sympy import diff

def sum_diff_order(f,x,n):
    g = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        g += diff(f,x,i)
    return g
```

So if you take `f` to be `x**10` and `n=5`, we get:

```
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> f = x**10
>>> sum_diff_order(f,x,5)
x**10 + 10*x**9 + 90*x**8 + 720*x**7 + 5040*x**6 + 30240*x**5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')
f = sp.Function('f')

n = 2
sum([f(x).diff(x,i) for i in range(n+1)])
```

> `f(x) + Derivative(f(x), x) + Derivative(f(x), x, x)`

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is an known integer, you can use something like `Add(*[diff(f(x), x, i) for i in range(n+1)])`. For symbolic `n` or infinity, it isn't possible yet, as there is [no way yet](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5575) to represent derivatives of symbolic order.